# Animation Library

Tags: actionscript-3, animation

I'm new to programming games, so I'll make it short and sweet:

Is there any standard practice for Flash/AS3 for organizing sets of game Sprites, especially related to movement. For Example, if I am moving left, and then down, there should be a fill in animation...if we want that fill-in animation, do we need to create an animation for every permutation of all 8 directions our character can move? Also, if we want to have dynamic shadows for our 2d sprites, do we have to draw a light source for every one of those 8 directions for all 8 directions?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no practice like that.

However, here are some tips from my personal experience:

- fill-ins:

  - if your sprite is small, just don't do any
  - other - SOME filling - for example, just from one direction to the one near it, and whenever the sprite rotates more than just on direction, play the fill-ins in a row
  - if you want to make ALL fill-ins, that would be a lot of work, I would say too much for something as small as a fill-in between two directions - better spend the time for something else
- light sources:

  - again, matters HOW visible this sprite will be - if it is something very small, just mirror and / or don't make any lighting at all
  - other - I am used to always make one sprite (fully redrawn, or just light redrawn - does not mater) - for all directions - it adds a nice touch to visible things like player sprite that are always going to be on the screen